# Google Anlaytics Embed API demo not working

Tags: google-analytics

I followed the steps from the webite below: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide#client-id

when I execute the code below I get the error message in my console
I have maintained "localhost" in my Javascript domain when I created my client id.
Can you pls advise? thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Embed API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Step 1: Create the containing elements. -->

<section id="auth-button"></section>
<section id="view-selector"></section>
<section id="timeline"></section>

<!-- Step 2: Load the library. -->

<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  // Step 3: Authorize the user.

  var CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXX';


  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  });

  // Step 4: Create the view selector.

  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector'
  });

  // Step 5: Create the timeline chart.

  var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:date',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'LINE',
      container: 'timeline'
    }
  });

  // Step 6: Hook up the components to work together.

  gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
    viewSelector.execute();
  });

  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    var newIds = {
      query: {
        ids: ids
      }
    }
    timeline.set(newIds).execute();
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Object {error: Object}
error: Object
errors: Array[1]
0: Object
message: "immediate_failed"
reason: "invalidParameter"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
message: "immediate_failed"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
 cb=gapi.loaded_0:433
_.nH cb=gapi.loaded_0:433
_.du.Vh cb=gapi.loaded_0:459
YP.Ka cb=gapi.loaded_0:466
_.k.iu cb=gapi.loaded_0:291
ix cb=gapi.loaded_0:431
(anonymous function) cb=gapi.loaded_0:433
h.BE cb=gapi.loaded_0:137
Wq cb=gapi.loaded_0:140
_.C.ye cb=gapi.loaded_0:140
Ap
```

Comment: Have you uploaded this to a server? If so could you please provide a link?

Comment: Did you specify a port as well? For each client ID you just specify a host and port. I.e. you can't just say `http:/localhost`, you must say `http://localhost:8080` (or whichever port number you choose).

Comment: Yes I added the port 8080. deployed the project on my local tomcat server and it gives the same error. I have ensured that the Analytics API has been turned "ON" and the Client ID is correct. thanks for the response. if you have any suggestions pls advise. thanks

Comment: @PhilipWalton why can't someone use just `http://localhost`? I could not find any documentation on this point and authentication on localhost does not seem to work indeed...

Comment: @MDT As far as I know, the origins need to match exactly. And origin includes protocol, hostname, and port. Note that if you're using the default port for your protocol and no port is shown when requesting `location.origin`, then you don't need to specify a port. But this is usually not the case on localhost.

Comment: @PhilipWalton I found the following on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project : "An origin is a unique combination of protocol, hostname, and port." However, using `http://localhost` as my application URL, with port=80 (not shown in the URL, neither running `location.origin`), I run into issues. Note that in my Google dev console I configured both `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:80`.

Answer (score 1):

Something must be wrong with your server or your client ID origins.

Copying and pasting that code exactly into jsbin.com (changing only the client ID) I'm able to get this working. All I had to do was add `http://run.jsbin.com` to the list of approved origins for the client ID I provided.

Here's a working example:
http://jsbin.com/batexelohuve/1/edit

If you add `http://run.jsbin.com` to your client ID's origins list and it works in jsbin, then it means something is wrong with your setup and not the code you provided.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong in the Generated ClientID because even when I create a new one with the exact same approved origin as you mentioned it still does not work on jsbin site. thanks for responding. any clue why does my client id not work? this is what I have: 541933319551-iodkf5q87ppr9btbb222gumnehs9smqp.apps.googleusercontent.com-->Client ID,http://run.jsbin.com/oauth2callback as the redirect and http://run.jsbin.com as the approved origin. thats all I got. wonder why it won't work with this client id? thanks so much for your quick response.

Comment: I also want to add that what I am observing is that it will show the output with "Google Analytics" bar and when I click on it it shows me this: 
401. That’s an error. I have created a new project and then a new client ID after activating the Analytics API but still no luck.

Error: invalid_client

no application name

Request Details

Answer (score 1):

Once your Client ID is generated, copy and paste it into your code and save your code as an `.html` instead of `.php`. For localhost, usually it is enough to just write it as `http://localhost`. Unless you specified a certain port so you might want to change it. Otherwise the usual one will do. To know which port your computer is listening to, access your `httpd.conf` file and find the listen command.

To add on, please don't forget to put the ``` `` ``` sign when you write the ID.

Hope that helps to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import JavaScript API in your code. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify Origin uri and Authorized uri properly, for example if your running demo in http://localhost:8080 then you have add this url in both Origin URI and Authorized URI  then you will get an access button in browser.